# Is the following metric topological equivalent to Euclidean metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d_S$ be a metric on $\mathbb{R}^p$ defined as $$ d_S(x,y) = \begin{cases} \| x- y\| & \text{when} \ x \  \text{and} \ y  \ \text{are linearly dependent} \\ \|x\| + \| y \| & \text{when}\  x \ \text{and} \ y \ \text{are linearly independent} \end{cases} $$

I need to determine if this metric is topologically equivalent to the normal Euclidean metric. I consider the case $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Since $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have that $d(x,y) \leq d_S(x,y)$ it follows that within every open ball for the Euclidean metric, there is contained also an open ball for the $d_S$ metric, so that the $d_S$ metric is topological finer than the Euclidean one.

I tried to find a counterexample for the other case, since I think it is false and they are not equivalent. But I could not come up with one.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not. It is much easier to approach the problem working with sequences, rather than with balls.

In $\Bbb R^2$ consider the sequence of points $(1, \frac 1 n)$; clearly, it tends to $(1,0)$ in the Euclidean topology. On the other hand, since $(1, \frac 1 n)$ and $(1, 0)$ are obviously linearly independent for every $n$,

$$d_S \left( (1, \frac 1 n), (1,0) \right) = \| (1, \frac 1 n) \| + \|(1, 0)\| = \sqrt {1+ \frac 1 {n^2}} + 1$$

which clearly does not tend to $0$, so $(1, \frac 1 n)$ does not tend to $(1,0)$ in the topology of $d_S$.

Since the two distances do not have the same convergent sequences, they are not topologically equivalent.

(Notice that if you had tried the same argument for $(0, \frac 1 n) \to (0,0)$, the convergence in $d_S$ would have hold; why? because $d_S$ is not translation-invariant, so the conclusion about convergence in a point cannot be automatically replicated in any other point.)

Comment: It's very easy to approach the problem directly via open sets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I won't disagree, but my mind is better trained for working with sequences (or nets) (I visualize them better), so of course that I find this easier.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider the set $(1,2)\times\{0\}$.